# Git-svn wants to dcommit my local master to a remote branch, not trunk

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, branching-and-merging

I must have read a dozen "how do I work with SVN branches in git-svn" questions, but I've never seen anything described like what's happening to me.  I'm trying a simple merge:

```
(master)% git co -b refac_merge
(refac_merge)% git svn dcommit -n
  Committing to (URL)/trunk
(refac_merge)% git merge remotes/refactor
(refac_merge)% git svn dcommit -n
  Committing to (URL)/branches/refactor # <-- WTF!
```

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391573/why-did-git-svn-remote-tracking-stopped-working) that sounds similar but the answer doesn't actually tell me how to *fix* it.  How can I tell git-svn that yes, I want the local branch that tracks the SVN trunk to *continue* tracking the SVN trunk post-merge?

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured out why my behavior is different from other questions I've seen.  Apparently it's important that my trunk (master) has not seen any changes since the point at which the remote branch was created.  This means that history is effectively already linear -- all my merges were FF.

If I check out the master, commit a trivial change, then check out the local `refac_merge` branch and `git rebase master`, it creates a whole new series of commits with the same messages, but different hashes (because they are now descendents of the trivial-change commit rather than the last trunk commit before the branch point).  Now, `git svn dcommit -n` correctly says that it will push to the SVN trunk.

Of course, this also leaves me with a really, really ugly git revision log.  Maybe there's a "best of both worlds" fix?